# Tor built from sources don't work (windows 10)

Tags: c, windows, proxy, mingw, tor

1. I downloaded sources from last stable version (tor-0.3.0.10)
2. Via MinGW build tor.exe (it wasn't easy but I did it :) )
3. Launched it.

**Problem is that sites don't work. I even don't know where to search for bug:**

1. Port 9050 is opened (I can go there by telnet).
2. "tor-resolve yandex.ru" works too.
3. Tor logs: 
   `code https://pastebin.com/8NHB5HMd`
4. Firewall is off.
5. I have another copy of tor (classic bundle). And it works fine.
   What can it be?

Comment: This is a hardly suitable question for Stack Overflow. It could be *anything* and probably something not directly even related to programming as such.

Comment: Yes, But I must solve it - it's my job).  So, maybe, there are some ideas or something, what can at least give the direction, where to search problem...

Comment: 'tor', downloaded from where?  What command did you use to download it?  Did you have all the warnings enabled when compiling?  Did you fix those warning or just ignore them.  How do you expect us to help if we cannot duplicate the problem?

Comment: tor downloaded from official site. BTW, I solved the problem, just changed tor source from stable to latest build.